# How can I plot a histogram using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram but can't seem to get it working.

My current code is using a line plot.

The code is below:

```
ticker = 'BGSF'
style.use('ggplot')

start_date = '01-01-2010'
end_date = '03-07-2021'

prices = pdr.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start=start, end=end)['Close']
returns = prices.pct_change()
last_price = prices[-1]

number_of_simulations = 10000
num_days = 90
simulation_df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(number_of_simulations):
    counter = 0
    daily_vol = returns.std()

    price_series = []

    price = last_price * (1 + np.random.normal(0, daily_vol))
    price_series.append(price)

    for y in range(num_days):
        if counter == 251:
            break

        price = price_series[counter] * (1 + np.random.normal(0, daily_vol))
        price_series.append(price)
        counter += 1

    simulation_df[x] = price_series
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Simulator')
plt.plot(simulation_df)
plt.axhline(y = last_price, color = 'r', linestyle = '-')
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('Price')

plt.show()
```

How can I change my code so that I get a histogram/distribution? Or something that will give a discernible visual representation of the data.

The data output looks like:

```
            0          1          2     ...       9997       9998       9999
0  13.628622  13.239073  12.377603  ...  11.604061  13.289695  12.351764
1  13.286069  13.229105  11.802037  ...  10.922634  13.369048  11.687561
2  13.278381  12.754887  11.293223  ...  10.722178  14.019657  11.468026
3  13.518970  13.051310  11.697287  ...  10.973414  14.125174  11.326635
4  12.696852  13.037619  11.126289  ...  10.840734  14.397820  11.226199
```

Comment: What is the data of `simulation_df` ?

Comment: I meant the structure of the dataframe (e.g the output of `df_simulated.head()`)

Comment: What is your expected outcome? What should be on the x/y-axis? And did you try my suggestions above?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate some data
col0 = np.random.randn(1000)
col1 = np.random.randn(1000)+10
df_simulated = pd.DataFrame({"0":col0,"1":col1})

last_price = 300
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
fig.suptitle("Simulator")
plt.hist(df_simulated,axes=ax) #plot histogram on "ax"
plt.axhline(y = last_price, color = 'r', linestyle = '-',axes=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Day')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
```

[image]